# How to add image(icon) to the CollapsingLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library

I want to add image(icon) to the collapsing layout i.e, left side of the title and i also want to add some subtitle to the Collapsing Layout.

When we scroll up. The image should move to the top with the title. How can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out this awesome [library](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout). It has attributes in XML only to add AVATAR view in it.

Comment: Cant we add without adding any libraries?

Comment: you can do, for that you have to understand the [library](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout) i provided you. Library included the source code so you can implement your own custom collapsing toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add image in Andrdoid.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/image"
```

Hope this helps.